# Flatpickr Default Date AND Time

Tags: jquery, flatpickr

I'm using jquery [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/). When I used it in the past, I was successful with setting default date. I was also successful with setting default time. Somehow, when I try to combine both they don't work. This is my code:

```
  let date = '8/8/20';
  let hour = '22';
  let min = '15';

  $("#date").flatpickr({
     defaultDate: new Date(date),
     defaultHour: hour,
     defaultMinute: min,
     enableTime: true,
     dateFormat: 'm/d/Y h:i K',
     minuteIncrement: 1
  });
```

If I comment:

```
defaultDate: new Date(date)
```

the time is correctly defaulted.

If I comment:

```
defaultHour: hour,
defaultMinute: min,
```

the date is correctly defaulted.

But when I use both together it only defaults the time and not the date.

I would appreciate if someone can look into this. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. Defaulting date to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format worked for me.

Like this:

```
$("#date").flatpickr({
  enableTime: true,
  minuteIncrement: 1,
  inline: true,
  defaultDate: "2020-11-26 14:30" 
});
```